# Trying to resize background with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to resize the background image of this website http://www.plusbits.co/ so it fills the browser using this script:

```
    <script>
    function goToByScroll(id){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("."+id).offset().top},'slow');
   }
    $(function()
   {
    $('.slide') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) )});
    $('.content-frame') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) - 63)+'px'});
    $('.content-frame-fifth') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) - 63)+'px'});

    $(window).bind('resize', function(){
        $('.slide') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) )});
        $('.content-frame') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) - 63)+'px'});
        $('.content-frame-fifth') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) - 63)+'px'});
    });
    });

    $('document').ready(function(){
$("div.content-frame").vAlign("div");
    });

    (function ($) {
$.fn.vAlign = function(container) {
    return this.each(function(i){
        if(container == null) {
            container = 'div';
        }
        $(this).html("<" + container + ">" + $(this).html() + "</" + container          + ">");
        var el = $(this).children(container + ":first");
        var elh = $(el).height(); //new element height
        var ph = $(this).height(); //parent height
        var nh = (ph - elh) / 2; //new height to apply
        $(el).css('padding-top', nh);
    });
};
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

And the following HTML and CSS:

```
    <!-- Home Start -->

    <section id="home" class="page">
    <article class=" slide content-frame container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <h1 class="responsive_text">Advertising
        <br />
        <span>Title</span></h1>
        <h3>Description</h3>
        <img id="da" src="images/da.png" a href="#fg" title="Frank & Gary"></a>
    </div>
</div>
    </article>
    </section> 

    <!-- Home End -->




    #home{
    min-height:100px;
    background-image:url(images/uog.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    padding:30px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

The website is built on boilerplate, but I can't seem to understand why the background image isn't resizing correctly. Do I have a problem with my HTML? Or is it the CSS? Or even the script itself? I'd appreciate any amount of help!

Comment: Well, switching to jQuery won't work, since you're already using it...

Comment: mate, it looks fine on my end. It covers all the screen perfectly.

Comment: @rand0m Is there not a white border underneath? Also, whay resolution are you running at? :)

Comment: I'm on 1900x1200 and no I don't have any border.

here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/EihuqgP.jpg

Comment: @rand0m Thank you! For some reason, on both Chrome and Safari on my computer I still get a border at the bottom, as you can see here:

Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/S795r8F.jpg
Safari: http://i.imgur.com/QQiP5gB.jpg

Could be something conflicting with Bootstrap?

Comment: sorry mate.. was away, enjoying my sunday :P

Answer (score 0):

firstly, If I were you, I'd use margin instead of padding

```
.page {
    margin-top: 57px!important; //height of header
}
```

and give the section a definitely height and the background image css rule to cover the region

```
#home {
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

while that should cover the entire 100% of the section. If that doesn't you next bet would be force setting these values using javascript.

```
window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById("home").style.margin = "0px auto !important";
     document.getElementById("home").style.height = "100% !important";
     document.getElementById("home").style.backgroundSize = "cover !important";
}
```

hope this works out for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working for me :/ I really don't understand why at all!

Comment: I also noticed that, when using Chrome to 'Inspect Element', no style is applied to the relevant class, and there's nothing under element.style either